# Restricting callback in model concern to right class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model concern that triggers callbacks related to an API for different models. Is there a way to cleanly separate in which class certain callbacks should be ran?

```
module Trackable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  TRACKER = Tracker.new()

  included do
      after_create_commit :do_this_to_user
      after_create_commit :do_this_to_order
  end

  def do_this_to_user

  end

  def do_this_to_order
  end

end
```

then I obviously include this concern into the relevant models, so I don't want both callbacks to be ran. I want the right callback for the right class. What's the best approach here?

Comment: Why are the concerns in the same file?

Comment: They share commonalities that are the same but not included in this example. So for example there are 3 methods that are cross model. Except these two.